# Calculate the Number or fixed time sessions that have expired between two dates

Tags: time, count

I need to calculate the number of sessions (Including counting part sessions as 1 each) that have expired between two dates & Times)

There is a further complication that the number of sessions that apply are related to the  location of the event with  either 2 or 3 sessions applying. I have those session categories generated into the spread sheet so it could  relate it to two separate tables to look up or a combined table with the 2 or 3 session element indicated.

The sessions are as follows
3 Sessions
Morning 6am to 2pm
Afternoon 2pm to 9pm
Evening 9pm to 6am

2 Sessions
Morning 6am to 2pm
Afternoon 2pm to 9pm

The start and finish date info is in date format with time so in UK format start 1st January 22 09:30am and 23 seconds by example 01/01/22 09:30:23 finish say 3rd January 2022 7:30:00pm so 03/01/22 07:30:00

In the case of an 3 session area The result would be 8 sessions 3+3+2

In the case of an 2 session area The result would be 6 sessions 2+2+2

Not sure how best to go about it as the sessions are also not the same period in hours.

any ideas and help would be welcomed
Regards
Iain

Rather stuck currently developing my skills and using these sort of forums to find solutions as I go. Haven't got my head around how to create a count for this one no problem with calculating total days and hours but can't think how I translate it to a count of parts of days.

Comment: You forgot to post your *attempt* to solve this problem, which someone might be able to help you fix/complete.